# Остановка приложения при нажатии кнопки ESC

Tags: java, многопоточность, файлы, клавиатура

Добрый вечер.
Возникла проблема, которую не могу реализовать.
Есть приложение которое считывает количество файлов в заданных папках и подпапках.
Данные по всем папкам приложение считывает одновременно.

Собственно вопрос, нужно добавить функционал, позволяющий остановить подсчет файлов по всем директориям при нажатии на кнопку ESC на клавиатуре и не потерять уже обработанные данные.

И можно ли остановить приложение таким образом, если оно запущено через окно команд(консоль винды)? Или его можно так остановить только если оно запущено через среду разработки?

Если кто знает как реализовать, помогите)

Comment: тебе нужно код предоставить или идею, направить тебя?

Comment: направить, я думаю будет достаточно)

Comment: один поток считывает файлы. и при каждом прохождении цикла проверяет какой нибудь флаг, напимер isContinue. длугой поток слушает keylistener на нажатие кнопки ESC. и если нажали, то меняет состояне isContinue=false.

Comment: спасибо за Ваш комментарий.
Лично для меня нет ничего зазорного спросить/направить. Вы же не с рождения все знаете, а где-то находите информацию, вычитываете, у кого-то спрашиваете, правильно?

Решение я не просил, спасибо!

Comment: @Senior Pomidor я как раз так и пытаюсь реализовать. Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Остановка консольного приложения посредством нажатия на клавишу `esc` не возможна. Придется навесить прозрачную форму а на нее уже навешивать слушатель

```
frame = new JFrame("KeyPress");
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getKeyCode() == 27) {
            // do something here
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

    }
});
frame.setOpacity(0.0f);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: ну и так оффтопик, [зачеркнутый текст, ссыль на готовое тестовое](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7X_8gPQARzzLWRnTDdCZVZuMkU/view?usp=sharing)